# how to make regex in python

Tags: python, regex

How to make a regex for this:

```
[1,31:14:18] SELECT * FROM T.roll1
```

Here what i tried `r'\[[^)] \s'` but it is not able to give me a output like:

```
(1, 31:14:18 ,SELECT * FROM T.roll1)
```

How to get this output?

Comment: You can use regex same as https://regex101.com/r/RdPxxw/1 `data = re.search(pattern, text, re.IGNORECASE)`
and after use `data.group(1-3)`

Comment: What do you need as output? Python2 or 3?

Comment: while ppl here start answering the "question" to get a karma, i would tell that the question is unclear!  (specially i can't understand, why here mentioned python if OP asked the question about how to make regex?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
import re
s = "[1,31:14:18] SELECT * FROM T.roll1"
r = [x.strip("[") for x in re.split(",|] ", s)]
print(r)
```

---

```
['1', '31:14:18', 'SELECT * FROM T.roll1']
```

---

[Python Demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/QsY)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do three different regex :

```
import re

test_str = "[1,31:14:18] SELECT * FROM T.roll1"

first_regex = r"\d+"
second_regex = r",(.*)]"
third_regex = r"] (.*)"

first_matches = re.findall(first_regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
second_matches = re.findall(second_regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
third_matches =  re.findall(third_regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

tuple_matches = first_matches[0], second_matches[0], third_matches[0]

print(tuple_matches)

# Output
# ('1', '31:14:18', 'SELECT * FROM T.roll1')
```